# Full/multiple room voice recognition

Tags: microphone, voice

What kind of microphone is suitable for use listening to an entire room for voice control purposes?

I've noticed the microphone array in the Kinect devices seems to be pretty good as this (still not as good as I'd like though). Should I go with one really good microphone or several simpler ones scattered around?

Also, what exists regarding to connectivity, i.e. are there any wlan microphones? Or should I use something else to avoid cables all over the place?

Comment: Something like this 

http://www.guitarcenter.com/Tascam/DR-05-Solid-State-Recorder-1297873814675.gc

this device and models similar to this one record in stereo within about 20 feet in every direction

Comment: The Kinect gadget takes four microphone capsules and sophisticated 16-bit processing of each microphone output just to achieve "pretty good" (your characterization) performance. I suspect that you are dramatically under-estimating the technology and complexity of the problem.  Just because they make it look simple/easy does NOT mean that it is.

Comment: @RichardCrowley Hehe yeah you're most definitely right. I haven't worked with anything audio related, so my definition for "pretty good" is probably way off. I guess we're not living on a ship from Star Trek yet..! But anyway then, to get Kinect-like or higher performance, I basically need something with multiple microphones and built-in processing hardware? Is there anything like that available or is a Kinect or two the way to go? I guess the voice recognition software also makes a big difference.

Comment: Have you considered the cost of a mixer? Especially if it is rated for 24 bit SACD audio. It can cost more than all of your microphones. Suggest you build this up in steps so the total cost is spread out over time.

Answer (score 1):

Use mic with headphones connect wire to game pad together it works wireless.

You cant use voice recognition effectively while there is loud music from tv set. 
but mic with headphones for xbox allows you recognize your speech.

voice recognition works only when it gets good sound from a speaker. So always better is use bluetooth mic set, plantronics or other. You can configure your mobile phone as a mic to send voice remotely.